# Django REST Framework: Add field from related object to ModelSerializer

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm trying to allow a field that belongs to a related object to be readable and writable from a ModelSerializer. I have a model `Group`:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def get_language(self):
        line = self.line_set.all()[0]
        return line.language
    ...
```

and corresponding serializer:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    language = serializers.CharField(source='get_language')

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'language')
        lookup_field= 'pk'
```

The `Group` model is related to the `Line` model, where the `language` field lives:

```
class Line(models.Model):
    ...
    language = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I'm trying to expose `Line.language` in the Group API for reading *and writing*. I've tried using CharField as above, but when I go to post a new model, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /AO/s/v2/group/

'get_language' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I also thought of trying a custom related field and implementing from_native, but that requires a queryset which isn't relevant here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have written `CharField`, not `RelatedField`.

Comment: fixed the typo, meant `CharField`

Comment: What if a Group has multiple Lines that have different languages?