# how to display my M2M model in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, serialization

I'm trying to display a 'nested' model in my API response and having trouble shaping the data.

I have the model the API is called from:

something like

```
class Rules(Model):
    conditions = models.ManyToManyField(RulesPoliciesConditions)
    ...
    ...

class RulesPoliciesConditions(Model):
    rules = models.ForeignKey(Rules, ...) 
    policies = models.ForeignKey(Policy, ...)
```

Rules and Policies are their own models with a few TextFields (name, nickname, timestamp, etc)

My problem is that when I use the Rules model to call a field called `conditions`, only the rules and policies PK display. I want to reach the other attributes like name, timestamp, nickname, etc.

I tried making my fields (in my Serializer) try to call specifically like "conditions__rules__name" but it's invalid, I also tried "conditions.rules.name" which is also invalid. Maybe I'm using the wrong field in my serializer, I'm trying out `conditions = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, queryset=q, slug_field="id")`

My intention is to display something like:

```
conditions: [
    {
     rules: {id: rulesId, name: rulesName, ...},
     policies: {id: policiesId, name: policiesName, ...}
    }, ...
]
```

or just even:
    conditions: [
        {
            rules: rulesName,
            policies: policiesName
        }, ...
    ]

since right now it just returns the rulesId and policiesId and it doesn't "know" about the other fields

EDIT: I found a relevant question on SO but couldn't get a relevant answer
[Django REST Framework: Add field from related object to ModelSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822339/django-rest-framework-add-field-from-related-object-to-modelserializer?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using ***nested serializers***. The level of **nesting** can be controlled/customized by various methods

```
class RulesPoliciesConditionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = RulesPoliciesConditions
        depth = 1


class RulesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    conditions = RulesPoliciesConditionsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Rules
```

Pass your **`Rules`** queryset to the **`RulesSerializer`** serializer to 
get the desired output

**Example**

```
rules_qs = Rules.objects.all()
rules_serializer = RulesSerializer(rules_qs, many=True)
data = rules_serializer.data
```

**References**
1. [serializer **`depth`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)
2. [Nested serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, I ended up using nested serializers and created extra ones based on what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested serializers for the purpose.

```
class RuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    class Meta:
         model = Rules(rulesId, rulesName)
         fields = ('id', 'email', 'country')

class RulesPoliciesConditionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     rules = RuleSerializer()
     policies = PolicySerializer()
     ...
```